# TDD on Rails 4: Features tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, tdd

Can anybody tell me how I can do a feature test in rails for a Post Edit Page?
I have a list of Post each one with an Edit Link. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it through RSPEC-

```
def postedit do
  before { visit posteditpage_path }
  subject { post }

  def posteach do
    it {should_contain editlink_path}
    end
  end
end
```